# Coded UI - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I wrote a simple Coded UI Test. I can run test, but when i try to debug the same, i am getting error "Unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details."

In the Test Output Pane, the following message is displaying.

**  Launching debugger with following information  **
------ Run test started ------
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:00,013) ==========

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

- You can refer to the following link for more details regarding the solution as provided by Microsoft experts:-
  [MSDN Refernce](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/91c2702d-0f83-4039-a8cd-5a53451adf57/coded-ui-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation).
  They are generally talking of enhancing the debug scenario to throw stack traces for all exceptions.

  - Alternately, you can check whether there are multiple instances of 'QTAgent32.exe' running or not on the system. Sometimes, stale processes lead to the issues as one reported by you.

Regards